# Moment.js issue in Ember application on Safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, safari, momentjs

I just started using moment.js in my ember/rails application. It works great on Chrome, but I'm running into some issue on Safari where the date shows up as: "undefined NaN/NaN/0NaN". I double-checked on console, and sure enough I'm getting an "Invalid date" error message. I think the problem is coming from how dates are formatted in Ember DS models, since the json itself returns a valid date string for both browsers. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

```
HTML:
    {{#each exam in model}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{#link-to 'exam' exam}}{{date exam.examDate}}{{/link-to}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}

Javascript:
    Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper "date", (date) ->
        moment(date).format('ddd L, h:mm a')

    App.Exam = DS.Model.extend(
        examDate: DS.attr('date')
    )
    App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend(
        revision: 12
        adapter: App.ApplicationAdapter
    )
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend(
        namespace: 'api/v1'
    )

JSON:
    {
        "exam_date":"2012-12-12 00:00:00"
    }
```

**Edit:**
If anyone else runs into this problem, I solved the issue by changing DS.attr("date") to DS.attr("string").

Comment: what's the json you are passing down for the examDate?

Comment: {"exam_date":"2012-12-12 00:00:00"} There's a couple other things, but I don't think they're relevant.

Comment: is that all the data for a single exam request?  will you add which addapter/serializer you may or may not be using and specifying?

Comment: Edited to add some extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have to guess a bit, since I don't want to go get the alpha releases of Ember Data, but I bet it's related to how your server is responding.

If you were to do `this.store.find('exam')` it would be expecting a result like this

```
{
  exams:[
    {
        "exam_date":"2014-06-12T14:40:25-07:00",
        "id":2
    },
    {
        "exam_date":"2014-06-12T14:40:25-07:00",
        "id":3
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

I'd definitely recommend upgrading your version of Ember Data to at least a 1.0 beta+.  You can read more about the changes here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

I put together an example of your app: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/680/edit

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! I actually am using Ember Data 1.0+, so the output is as you mentioned above (sorry about that, took it out before posting above). I just broke something in the code so that Chrome shows the same thing that Safari does, so my guess is that you're right.